# AS3 shared objects in IOS and Android devices

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, save, shared-objects

i´m creating apps using AS3 and saving scores in sharedObjects. Smooth...
The problem is that when i create a new version of the app and upload to the Android Market or AppStore, the sharedObject saved in the user device goes to Zero(0).
Is there any way to keep this data in the device after updating the app?
Thanks.